# What happens when I change a large file while a user is downloading it?

Tags: php, download

What happens in the following situation:

In the backend, the admin has uploaded many (large) files, zipped them, resulting in `example.zip`.

At a certain point, a visitor comes to the site and starts downloading this large file. The admin has added some more files and pressed "convert to zip". It starts zipping and the result writes to the same location, same name `example.zip`.

**The user was at 50% downloading, does the new zip interfere with this?** I'm aware that the PHP script gets loaded into the memory, but if you have large files, those don't fit.

```
 // OPENING THE FILE IN READ-ONLY
$fp = fopen($filepath, "r");
$bufferlength = 1024;
while (!feof($fp) ){
    // READ A BUFFER SIZE OF THE FILE
    $buffer = fread($fp, $bufferlength);
    echo $buffer;
    $buffer = "";
    flush(); // THIS IS ESSENTIAL FOR LARGE DOWNLOADS
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Maybe I can improve the question...

Comment: Have you tested this? this case is highly unlikely to ever get implement. Fopen will open the file the descriptor, fread will read until the end, if someone downloading an changing file will simple download an zip than can't be opened or an never ending request as the file is read and steamed chunk by chunk until the end is found.

Comment: I'm going to implement this, so I like to know beforehand what to look out for :) This will be on a host where resources are limited, so I can not simply rename it and make another file. Same principle though, if I delete it while someone is downloading (and place another named file for todays date in return), what happens now?

Comment: And presenting the user a zip of 500MB which doesn't open is bad service, I'm not aiming for that :)

Comment: It kind of depends on the file system and its configuration. In general, writing to an file opened for reading will corrupt the read data, depending on what was already read and where data is written. Deleting a file opened for reading doesn't delete the file until the read handle is closed.

Comment: @Martijn the host might have limited resources, but there are many file hosting services that offer some GB for free, with SDKs to work with.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of those, but those aren't an option. This is an expantion to where they're already at, so this is what I;m stuck with :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I still don't know the answer to my question, I do know that a file which is ***deleted*** doesn't actually get deleted when it's in use, untill it is no longer in use.

This means that when a user is downloading a large file and an admin deletes it, it will keep on going for the downloading user, but will appear as deleted for all others.

In this case I created a `downloadZip.php` which, when clicked, gets you the lastest version of the zip. When a admin re-zips everything, it'll result in a `name2.zip`, then a `name3.zip` etc.

UserA clicks download, gets `name1.zip`. Admin deletes, UserA is unaffected, user B will now get `name2.zip` when he/she clicks the `downloadZip.php`.